# Magento add jQuery slider in my home page where admin can upload images

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

I am quite newbie in magento. I have got a jquery plugin. The link is [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/). Now I want to include this slider in my magento template. Where admin will upload the images and the image should come in the slider just like the jquery plugin images. So can someone kindly tell me how to use this jQuery plugins in my magento template. Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks..

Comment: Was your question answered? Is there any more information that you could provide to help us give you a clearer answer?

Answer (score 1):

[I suggest that you use a Static Block.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/cms_block/edit)

Although Magento has the home page as a CMS page type where you can make edits, the static block feature allows you to focus on just the one region of the page without the admin needing to worry about the other content.

To include this newly created static block on your cms homepage, add the following tag (assuming it's named "homepage_slider"):

```
{{block id='homepage_slider'}}
```